# "Invalid video format" after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, video, vga

I am having this problem every time I install Ubuntu on my PC. I used to connect my PC via a VGA cable to my screen and every time I install Ubuntu on any PC that uses a VGA cable, I will get an error message saying

```
Unsupported video file, invalid video format
```

It also says `cannot display this video mode`. One time, I installed a DVI-D video cable and it worked fine. I just want to know why don't VGA cables work when installing Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried to set the resolution to lower than 1280x1024 from System Settings- Displays?

Comment: Please specify your PC's graphics card.

Comment: what's the output of `xrandr`

Answer (score 0):

We first need to find out if your system recognizes the current resolution. If it does then perhaps we can force it.

Run the following commands in the terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install xresprobe
sudo ddcprobe
```

This should reveal the supported resolutions.

Then find out the name of your interface, like VGA1 or HDMI1 etc. as an example I am using HDMI2.
Also make note of the Resolution and refresh rate. (I assume you know these already).

Now issue this command:

```
xrandr
```

Now replace the resolution and refresh rate in the command below with your own.

```
gtf 1920 1080 59.9
```

From the output copy every thing after the word "Modeline"

What you copy will be something like this: `"1920x1080_59.90" 172.51 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118 -HSync +Vsync`

Having done that run this one after another in Terminal using your outputs.

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_59.90"  172.51  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync

xrandr --addmode HDMI2 "1920x1080_59.90"

xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode "1920x1080_59.90"
```

This should give you your desired monitor resolution. This is only temporary.

To make this permanent you will have to write a script and save it as follows:

```
mkdir ~/Scripts
gedit ~/Scripts/fixresolution.sh
```

This will open a blank document with gedit. Add following to the document and save it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_59.90"  172.51  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI2 "1920x1080_59.90"
xrandr --output HDMI2 --mode "1920x1080_59.90"
```

Now to load this file at each start-up run following in terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/Scripts/fixresolution.sh
sudo ln -s ~/Scripts/fixresolution.sh /etc/X11/Xsession.d/45fixresolution
```

Try restarting with your wide-screen and see with xrandr if it is using 1280x1024. 
If it is then use your old dell monitor and see if it works.

Good Luck